# fitting a rectangle into a semi-circle

Tags: geometry

I have a question about fitting a rectangle into a semi circle. I have a futon that I want to fit into a round tent that is broken up by a center pole. The tent is 14 ft diameter and with the center pole, the space left is only about 6 1/2 feet from the pole to the edge of the circular tent. The futon I want to fit in it is 80x60 inches. Can I get it to fit? I looked at your previous questions about a rectangle into a semi circle but I just can't do the math.

Comment: You can fit the futon in the tent. 
This is because $\sqrt{(6 + 60)^2 + (80/2)^2} \approx 77.17 < 84$.
First place the futon so that the center of its longer side is touching the
outside of central pole. You then "rotate" the futon with respect to the pole.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is going to fit just fine (ignoring any three dimensional effects and working with a purely 2D model). You will even have a little bit of room around it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a diagram of the problem with $JKLM$ representing the futon.

Just show that $OK^2=OP^2+PK^2<84^2$.

P.S. The diagram units are in feet rather than inches.

[image: futon placed inside tent]